# How to display dynamic text inside images with HTML and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm developing php site using codeigniter and I need to display HTML text inside an image from a database. The text value will change between profiles. This is the image:

[image]

"$40" is the dynamic text. How should I proceed? Here is the HTML:

```
  <button class="btn btn-danger" id="buy-btn" 
       data-toggle="modal" 
       data-target=".package-buy-modal">BOOK NOW</button>

  <img id="price-tag" 
       src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets_profile/img/price.png">
```

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? CSS (`transform: rotate(45deg);`) can do this?

Comment: Why do you need to use a canvas? Is it absolutely necessary? There are several ways to get this done; css-rotate, php-gd, css-canvas. php-gd is probably the most "solid" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
 <span id="price-tag-value"> 40$ </span>
 <img id="price-tag" src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets_profile/img/price.png"/>
```

CSS

```
#price-tag-value{
-o-transform: rotate(32deg); //change the deg value accordingly
-moz-transform: rotate(32deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(32deg);
}
```

Comment: keep in mind this has limited browser support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d